# Trusted Assembly Location

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a trusted assembly with **'sys.sp_add_trusted_assembly'**.

It is saved in the server, I can see it with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.trusted_assemblies
```

The problem is that I can not see it in the assembly list of my database:
[image]

For example, I tried to drop the assembly again by using all the possible databases in the server including the 'master', it couldn't find it.

In which database is my trusted assembly saved and how can I add it to my own database?

Comment: If it is SAFE then you should see it under the database that you have executed CREATE ASSEMBLY command

Comment: But UNSAFE assemblies or trusted assemblies are not listed on SSMS.